# jQuery autosave not working as it should

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autosave

I have a couple of scripts i have written below that work great seperately, but together they don't work as they should. Let me post the code and then explain the issue:

Autosave function:

```
<script>
        function autosave() {
            $('form').each(function() {
                var string = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
                var $this = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "add_room.php",
                data: string,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    var saveIcon = $this.siblings('.saveIcon');
                    $this.siblings('[type=hidden]').val(data);
                    saveIcon.fadeIn(750);
                    saveIcon.delay(500).fadeOut(750);
                    $('#message').text('The id of the inserted information is ' + data);
                }
                });
            });
        }
        setInterval(autosave, 10 * 1000);
</script>
```

AJAX post and return script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').on('click', '.save', function(e) {
            var string = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
            var $this = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "add_room.php",
                data: string,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    var saveIcon = $this.siblings('.saveIcon');
                    $this.siblings('[type=hidden]').val(data);
                    saveIcon.fadeIn(750);
                    saveIcon.delay(500).fadeOut(750);
                    $('#message').text('The id of the inserted information is ' + data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#addForm').on('click', function(){
            $('<form method="post" action="add_room.php"><label for="itemName[]">Item</label><input type="text" name="itemName[]"><label for="itemPhoto[]">Photo</label><input type="text" name="itemPhoto[]"><input type="hidden" name="itemId[]" value=""><input type="hidden" name="itemParent[]" value="<?=$_GET["room"]?>"><div class="saveIcon" style="display: none; color: green;">SAVED!</div><div class="save">Save Item</div></form>').fadeIn(500).appendTo('.addItem');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="add_room.php">
                <label for="itemName[]">Item</label>
                <input type="text" name="itemName[]">
                <label for="itemPhoto[]">Item</label>
                <input type="text" name="itemPhoto[]">
                <input type="hidden" name="itemId[]" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="itemParent[]" value="<?=$_GET['room']?>">
                <div class="saveIcon" style="display: none; color: green;">SAVED!</div>
                <div class="save">Save Item</div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?PHP

    require_once('dbConfig.php');

    $item = $_POST['itemName'];
    $photo = $_POST['itemPhoto'];
    $id = $_POST['itemId'];
    $parentId = $_POST['itemParent'];

    foreach($item as $key => $val) {

        if(!$id[$key]) {

            if ($stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT test (test_title, test_desc, test_parent) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"))
            {
                // Use an s per variable passed to the string, example - "ss", $firstname, $lastname
                $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $val, $photo[$key], $parentId[$key]);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();

                echo $db->insert_id;
                //echo "success";
            }
            // show an error if the query has an error
            else
            {
                echo "ERROR: Could not prepare Insert SQL statement.";
            }

        } 
            else
        {
            if ($stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE test SET test_title = ?, test_desc = ? WHERE test_id = ?"))
            {
                // Use an s per variable passed to the string, example - "ss", $firstname, $lastname
                $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $val, $photo[$key], $id[$key]);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();

                echo $id[$key];
                //echo "success";
            }
            // show an error if the query has an error
            else
            {
                echo "ERROR: Could not prepare Update SQL statement.";
            }
        }

    }

?>
```

Now, what happens with the second script is, when used on its own without the autosave, when you fill out the form and click save it takes that forms data and saves it to the necessary rows in a database, and then returns the id of what was just saved and puts that data in a hidden field so that the php script can work out if an insert query is needed or an update query is needed(when the returned id is present). There is also a clickable div called addForm which then appends another form set below the one(s) present and again, when it's save button is clicked ONLY this form is saved/updated in the database. When i trigger the autosave like i have in my code, the autosave literally takes ALL the forms and saves them as new entries but doesn't return the id/update the hidden field to trigger the update sequence. Can you shed ANY light on this at all? It's really bugging me. Have tried explaining this as best i can, sorry it's so long. It's a bit of a complicated one! haha

Comment: `$(this).closest("form")` is redundant in the `autosave` function, it could simply be `$(this)`. However, that shouldn't affect the outcome.

Comment: Shall i remove it and see if it does anything different?

Comment: You should remove it, but it won't do anything different. `.closest()` looks at the current selection before looking at ancestors, so it'll stop immediately on the current element because it's a form. However, you could instead move all that logic inside of yet another function that is available everywhere, and just use that function in all three places to ensure all three places are doing exactly the same thing. It will also shorten your code quite a bit, and may help with debugging.

Comment: Oh! sorry i'm tired haha, completely see what you mean now. Have updated that locally. It still works, and works as it should but it just doesnt return the ID for that insert and add it to the hidden field which then would trigger the update. Like i say, works perfectly outside the autosave; saves the fields, updates the id and then updates if the id is sent again via ajax

Comment: Just saw the other bit of your message. Can you write a quick demo so i can see what you mean about using another function? Not sure how to utilise it properly

Comment: Like this: http://pastebin.com/G2YFVp8t

Comment: Thanks mate, i'll try this out in a second :)

Comment: Sorry, pasted wrong one, refresh page and copy link again. Or just click this one: http://pastebin.com/G2YFVp8t

Comment: Have tried that mate, the save thing just does nothing now, no message, no insert; nothing :(

Comment: Thats both clicking save and autosave btw

Comment: Well, at least it's consistent now, :p -- I had the first part of it out of order: http://pastebin.com/vmHhgkXQ

Comment: Haha more issues now :P It's doing less than before. It SAVES but it saves every entry and a new row, even if i update the form field. Even when i turn autosave off, it still does it. Whereas with my code it would return the data from the ajax and then trigger an update if the id was found. Nearly there! haha

Comment: In the autosave function (and in @KevinB's pastebin postForm function) $this == the Form, so $this.siblings('[type=hidden]').val(data); is trying to put the data in siblings of the Form not in inputs inside the form.

Comment: so i should be using children(); ?

Comment: Nice catch, that needs to be .find then. http://pastebin.com/0QTZzX6X though that doesn't explain it saving every entry and every row when autosave is turned off.

Comment: @KevinB and bbird that has worked BEAUTIFULLY. Thanks so much for helping me out on this. Much appreciated!

Comment: @KevinB if you'd like to either paste a link to the pastebin or copy the code as an answer, i shall accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a few changes to the organization of the code, which then leads to making it easier to identify the errors.

http://pastebin.com/0QTZzX6X

```
function postForm(form) {
    var $this = $(form);
    var string = $this.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_room.php",
        data: string,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            var saveIcon = $this.find('.saveIcon');
            $this.find('[type=hidden]').val(data);
            saveIcon.fadeIn(750);
            saveIcon.delay(500).fadeOut(750);
            $('#message').text('The id of the inserted information is ' + data);
        }
    });
}

function autosave() {
    $('form').each(function() {
        postForm(this);
    });
}
setInterval(autosave, 10 * 1000);
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.save', function(e) {
        postForm($(this).closest('form').get(0));
    });

    $('#addForm').on('click', function(){
        $('<form method="post" action="add_room.php"><label for="itemName[]">Item</label><input type="text" name="itemName[]"><label for="itemPhoto[]">Photo</label><input type="text" name="itemPhoto[]"><input type="hidden" name="itemId[]" value=""><input type="hidden" name="itemParent[]" value="<?=$_GET["room"]?>"><div class="saveIcon" style="display: none; color: green;">SAVED!</div><div class="save">Save Item</div></form>').fadeIn(500).appendTo('.addItem');
    });
});
```

Basically i took logic that was duplicated and placed it into a more generic function.